# Flutter - Add decimals on a dynamic value field

Tags: flutter

In Flutter i have a dropdown (we can call maxim field) to select total length. Then in index field we can add values with the same length of dropdown. When i add the value in index field i need to add '.000'.

I try to use [masked package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_masked_text) but i can't concatenate the index field value.

The code is similar to

```
  int inputMaxValue=1;
  var inputIndexValue = new MaskedTextController(mask: inputMaxValue.text+'.000');
```

Return

> Only static members can be accessed in initializers

¿Anybody know can i fix this problem?

Comment: add more code to check where is the error

Comment: inputMaxValue is an integer and you are using `inputMaxValue.text`, It would be better if you add more code to see what's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think `MaskedTextController` is unnecessary in your case, simply change `int inputMaxValue` to `double inputMaxValue` and possibly add `.toStringAsFixed(3)` to achieve 3 decimals after the dot.

e.g.

```dart
double inputMaxValue = 1.0;
String inputIndexValue = "${inputMaxValue.toStringAsFixed(3)}";
```

---

However, if you want to keep the `flutter_masked_text` package - you should avoid using dynamic strings for the `mask` property. Error `Only static members can be accessed in initializers` appears supposedly because you declare the masked controller variable within the class, not in it's enclosing methods (e.g. `initState`).

In case of `MaskedTextController`, only static strings should be used for the `mask` property.

e.g. this is what I use to format phone number field:

```dart
MaskedTextController(mask: "(000) 000-0000")
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe NumberFormat can help

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

```
final price = 123;
final formater = NumberFormat("#,##0.000");
print(formater.format(price));
```

output: 123.00